# Scrapy Depth limit changing Itself

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am crawling a website using Scrapy. Lets say there are 150 pages to crawl , the site has pagination where one page give url of the next page to crawl.
Now, my spider stop by itself, with the following logs:

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 38096,
 'downloader/request_count': 55,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 55,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5014634,
 'downloader/response_count': 55,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 55,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 17, 19, 12, 11, 607000),
 'item_scraped_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 58,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 36,
 'response_received_count': 55,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 55,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 55,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 55,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 55,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 17, 19, 9, 13, 893000)}
```

the `request_depth_max` sometimes become 51, and now it 36. But in my settings I have it as `DEPTH_LIMIT = 1000000000`

I have also tried setting DEPTH_LIMIT to 0, but still the spider stops by itself, is there any setting that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stat `request_depth_max` is not a setting, it just means the highest depth your spider reached in this run.

Also [`DEPTH_LIMIT` defaults to 0](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=depth_limit#depth-limit) which equates to infinity.

Comment: If that is not  a setting, and I am having DEPTH_LIMIT  as 100000, then why my spider is not covering all pages, i.e. why it stops after a certain depth.

Comment: @sagar it probably has nothing to do with depth but with your code. You'd have to provide your code for more help, probably open up a new issue.

Comment: I found the issue, actually, the site is sending no response(with http status code 200) after making few requests, so the code couldn't find the link of next page after making several hits. Thanks , anyways

Comment: @sagar Great! Could you accept the answer so other people have this problem they can navigate it faster.